# How to access class members with same name in extension function in Kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, extension-function

i'm new to kotlin for android. and i want to access class member that having same name in extension function.
for example:

```
   var visibility = null //class level variable

    //EXTENSION FUNCTION
    fun ProgressBar.changeVisibleState(flag: Boolean) {
        if (flag)
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
        else
            visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
```

how can i access `visibility` in `changeVisibleState` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a [*qualified this*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified) `this@Hello` you can access `Hello`'s property instead of `ProgressBar`'s.

```
class Bye {
    var visibility: Int = 0 //class level variable
}
class Hello {
    var visibility: Int = 0 //class level variable

    fun Bye.changeVisibleState(flag: Boolean) {
        //access Bye's prop
        visibility = if (flag) 1 else 2
        //access Hello's prop
        this@Hello.visibility = 12
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` operator.

```
class Hello {
    var visibility: Int = 0 //class level variable

    //EXTENSION FUNCTION
    fun ProgressBar.changeVisibleState(flag: Boolean) {
        if (flag)
            this@Hello.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        else
            this@Hello.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
}
```